# VB.Net: Inserting Shape in Certain Cell

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, cell, shapes

I'm attempting to insert a shape at a specific cell, say (5,5) for instance. I am able to get the shape into excel, but can't figure out how to put it in (5,5). After research, I know that shapes sit on top of cells in worksheets. I have also learned that `.Range` could be helpful here.

I'm just uncertain of how to put these pieces of the puzzle together to make my shape go to (5,5).

`xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 17, 0, 15, 13)`

Also, am a beginner to vb.net so if you could dumb everything down i'd really appreciate it!

EDIT: 
Tried this code.. but it put the number `7` in (5,5) instead of the shape.

`Dim aNew As MsoAutoShapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5) = anew`

Also tried:

`xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Left, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Top, 15, 13)`

but received an error of

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred`

EDIT: Code that worked...

`xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 5)).Left, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 5)).Top, 25, 14)`

Comment: VB.NET and vba are 2 different things.

Comment: I thought they were similar in this regard; My apologies if they aren't!

Comment: can you get the left and top properties from the cell? in vba `cells(5,5).top`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that's what I was reading about, but i'm not sure how to go about it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've looked into that, but i'm confused on the application of it

Comment: Its not that difficult that assigning a worksheet object xlWorksheet as you've done.    xlWorkSheet.get_range(xlWorkSheet.cells(5.5)).top maybe, not in VS at mo.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That makes perfect sense on paper but for some reason I'm getting an error when I try to run it. See EDIT in original post

Comment: Debug it then, use xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Top breaking it down, so, is xlWorkSheet ok, is xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5) ok, is xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)) ok, where is the error, break down big statements, in fact start with them in their constituent parts, then look at their returns and chain together as you've done here `xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Left, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Top, 15, 13)`
We cant see your code/screen,

Comment: @Nathan_Sav if you make an answer i'll accept it. Finally got it to work with your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something along these lines`xlWorkSheet.get_range(xlWorkSheet.cells(5.5)).top` or `cells(5.5).top`

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred

Debug, use `xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Top` breaking it down, so, is `xlWorkSheet` ok, is `xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)` ok, is `xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5))` ok, where is the error, break down big statements, in fact start with them in their constituent parts, then look at their returns and chain together as you've done here `xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscel‌​esTriangle, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Left, xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 5)).Top, 15, 13)` We cant see your code/screen

Answer (score 2):

Using VBA I'd go for this to print in B2, you can use height and width to change button height and width:

```
Dim button As Shape
Set button = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
button.Top = Range("B2").Top
button.Left = Range("B2").left
button.Height = 50
button.Width = 100
```

or in your example:

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, Range("B2").left, Range("B2").Top, 15, 13)
```